# Express mathematically that a vector has an element greater zero

Tags: equations, cases

This might not only be related to latex, but I'm struggling to find a way of expressing a condition which is if a vector contains at least one element that is greater than zero.

Currently I have this, but I'm not sure if it is mathematically correct and neither is the latex code that great:

```
\begin{equation}
    f(x)= 
    \begin{cases}
        1,& \text{if } \exists \, x_i > 0\\
        0,              & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
    \qquad s \in \mathbb{R}_+, x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, n \in \mathbb{N}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: `A vector $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is called \emph{nonpositive} if $x_i\le0$, for every $i$. Define $f(x)=0$ if $x$ is nonpositive and $f(x)=1$ otherwise.`

Comment: That's an abuse of `\exists`. Properly, you should write `\exists i\colone x_i>0`, but that is awkward. Just use words instead. I think `\text{if some $x_i>0$}` is clear enough, though again, `\text{if $x_i>0$ for some $i$}` is more correct. But the rewording by @egreg is pretty good, too.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbf{x}=
  \begin{pmatrix}x_1&x_2&\dots&x_n\end{pmatrix}'\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Then
\[
f(\mathbf{x})=
\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if $\max_i x_i>0$,}\\
0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\]

In words: $f(\mathbf{x})=1$ if at least one $x_i>0$, $i=1,\dots,n$.
\end{document}
```